# JavaScript for Apache Jena TripleStore

Tags: javascript, sparql, fuseki, apache-jena

i've build a TDB-Store with Apache Jena and now i want to use the data from my store to implement some nice visualizations. So after all it's necessary to access my TDB with JavaScript.

I guess, there are two possibilities to archieve this:

No. 1: Run a Fuseki Server and run sparql queries on it's endpoint (i.e. `http://localhost:3030/dataset/sparql`). How can i query this endpoint with js?

No. 2: Access the TDB directly from js. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance, FFoDWindow

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to answer the question by myself:

For No 1.:

1. You need to run your Fuseki-Server as usual. The `SPARQL`-endpoint is now `http://localhost:3030/nameOfYourDataset/sparql`.
2. It's time to encode your query to an url-friendly format, i.e. with the `encodeURIComponent`-function. I did it as follows:

   ```
   var queryUrl = url_to_endpoint + "?query" + encodeURIComponent(query) + "&format=json";
   ```
3. Now call `queryUrl` with ajax and you receive your result in json-format.

I guess No. 2 was kind of a silly question and the first method is the best way to obtain your data.

I hope this answer helps further reader. See you,

FFoDWindow